# Log time spent on emacs org-mode capture items

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I have a capture template set up to file journal entries in an org file.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "/home/emil/org/journal_.org")
     (file "/home/emil/org/journal-template.org") :prepend :clock-in))
```

I want to clock out and output the time elapsed on the clock started with :clock-in when the capture is filed, but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got the template slightly wrong.
Here's how I have it:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      `(("t" "todo" entry
             (file+headline (concat org.d "gtd.org") "Tasks")
             "* TODO %^{Brief Description} %^g     \nAdded: %U  %i\n  %?\n"
             :clock-in t :clock-resume t)))
```

So that's `:clock-in t`, not just plain `:clock-in`.